# npm ERR! registry error parsing json - While trying to install Cordova for Ionic Framework in Windows 8

Tags: npm

I was trying to instal Ionic framework in my Windows 8 system and was trying to install Cordova first.

I'm getting this error while trying to install Cordova, that says

```
Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.4 (x64) and npm.

C:\Users\Sworup>npm install -g cordova ionic
npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1424-df7f
43fe\registry.npmjs.org\underscore\-\underscore-1.7.0.tgz
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1424-df7f
43fe\registry.npmjs.org\npm\-\npm-2.1.3.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read

npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR! tar.unpack untar error C:\Users\Sworup\AppData\Local\Temp\npm-1424-df7f
43fe\registry.npmjs.org\prompt\-\prompt-0.2.12.tgz
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs
\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.4
npm ERR! npm  v2.10.1

npm ERR! unexpected eof
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Sworup\npm-debug.log

C:\Users\Sworup>
```

My system configuration is as follows:

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm -v
2.10.1

C:\Windows\System32>node -v
v0.12.4

C:\Windows\System32>git --version
git version 1.9.4.msysgit.1
```

I already did

```
C:\Windows\System32>npm cache clear
```

before running the install command to no use.

I tried changing the registry to http still no use.

I tried installing **Ionic framework** separately, still no luck.

I tried installing **Phonegap**, same errors as above.

I'm just stuck at this point and have no idea what to do.

Comment: update node js to latest version [http://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version](http://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

In my case, I had a very old version of npm. Upgrading npm using `sudo npm install npm -g` fixed the problem for me. Additionally I also did `rm -rf node_modules` and `npm cache clean` and `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"`

Comment: Great. I had to use `sudo npm cache clean` followed by `sudo npm install npm -g`

Comment: npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/" < is helpful without knowing issue..

Answer (score 20):

I had similar problem. I rаn `npm cache clear`, closed android SDK manager(which was open before) and re-ran `npm install -g cordova` and that was enough to solve the problem.

Comment: npm cache clear is not working for some reason. But just now the installation worked in one of my colleague's system. I'll try it again in a while.

Answer (score 9):

```
npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"
```

Solved the issue for me. Note that it wouldn't accecpt a forward slash at the end of the url and it had to be entered exactly as shown above.

Comment: Thank you !, this worked for me, as I had setted it to "http://registry.npmjs.eu/"  an this server is down. So I didn't figure out, this was the reason.

Answer (score 4):

first I had to delete my registry  by using `npm config delete registry` and register new value using `npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org"`

Answer (score 2):

In my case all Internet access must run through a proxy and npm was not configured with the proxy to reach http://registry.npmjs.org.

I ran `npm install --log-level verbose` to get more information and saw that the response had HTML stating I was not authenticated with the proxy.

Running the following fixed it (replacing below with your username/password/proxy address:

```
npm config set proxy 'username:password@your.proxy.com'
npm config set https-proxy 'username:password@your.proxy.com'
```

I do not advise putting the password in raw text instead using something like cntlm to set up a local proxy that delegates to the real proxy.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem when trying to upgrade pm2 to the latest version.

Thanks to sdm's answer I did `npm update npm -g` and it did the trick for me.

Answer (score 1):

npm install -g @angular/cli --registry http://registry.npmjs.org/ worked for me

Answer (score 1):

For me following fixed the issue:

1. npm cache clear
2. Made sure that NPM & Git proxies are set properly

In this case Git proxy may not be required.

Answer (score 0):

My `npm install` worked fine, but I had this problem with `npm update`. To fix it, I had to run `npm cache clean` and then `npm cache clear`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the following fixed my issue:

1. Set the registry: npm config set registry "http://registry.npmjs.org/"
2. Removed the entry in hosts file (using Windows 7) =>  C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

Answer (score 0):

In my case artifactory was down. npm install command is throwing below error.

npm ERR! registry error parsing json

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post; instead, provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker.

Answer (score -1):

pls remove the

HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
proxy
from the npmrc file