# Which NodeJS version should I use for Ionic?

Tags: node.js, cordova, ionic-framework

I was using Node version 0.10.40 to run Ionic. It seems running fine, however ionic shows this message every-time I run it:

```
******************************************************
 Upgrade warning - for the CLI to run correctly,
 it is highly suggested to upgrade the following:

 Please update your Node runtime to version  >=0.12.x

******************************************************
```

So, I update my Node to version 0.12.7. But then when I try to reinstall cordova & ionic, I get a series of warning & errors such as:

```
npm WARN engine cordova-js@4.0.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.7","npm":"2.11.3"})
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" "ionic"
npm ERR! node v0.12.7
npm ERR! npm  v2.11.3

npm ERR! unexpected eof
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>
```

It end up fail to install. So, what version of NodeJS should I use?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787702/npm-err-registry-error-parsing-json-while-trying-to-install-cordova-for-ionic ?

Comment: @tgo Thanks. But that thread doesn't solve the problem of the update warning message.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if you are updating nodeJs to 0.12.7 version means you need to update your cordova framework version also ... if you don't want to update your cordova means you need to uninstall nodeJS 0.12.7 verison and install 0.10.4

Comment: Update cordova to what version? Where did you get this info from ?

Comment: you have to update cordova version > 4.0.0 , I faced this type of error when I am installing cordova and I read this article in the development tools of cordova