# Why is my npm install not working?

Tags: node.js, npm

Since this morning I am trying to get npm install working again, it is also using a proxy but my credentials havent changed. I upgraded to node v7 and tried this link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30787702/npm-err-registry-error-parsing-json-while-trying-to-install-cordova-for-ionic
```

When I try npm install I get this error:

```
[ERROR] npm ERR! registry error parsing json
```

How do I get npm install working again?

Answer (score 0):

May be temporary npm registry glitch, or corrupted local npm cache.

Run

```
 [npm cache clean]
```

and try again later.

Comment: Been trying that for the last hour