# Why is my npm install failing on Mac for React Native?

Tags: macos, react-native, npm, npm-install

New to React Native I've made sure to install node.js from [here](https://nodejs.org/en/) and after install I'm told:

```
Node.js v9.5.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
npm v5.6.0 to /usr/local/bin/npm
```

I can verify the node version:

```
node --version: v9.5.0
```

I ran the documentation's [getting started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) for `npm install`:

```
npm install -g create-react-native-app
```

and also referenced `building projects` and installed watchman with brew:

```
watchman 4.9.0
```

in the terminal ran: `npm install -g react-native-cli` and terminal: `npm start` and I get:

```
grim ~/react-native/react-native npm start

> react-native@1000.0.0 start /Users/grim/React-Native/react-native
> /usr/bin/env bash -c './scripts/packager.sh "$@" || true' --

module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'graceful-fs'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/grim/React-Native/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
grim ~/react-native/react-native
```

After research I found [NPM, cannot find 'graceful-fs', no matter what I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379919/npm-cannot-find-graceful-fs-no-matter-what-i-do) and in terminal ran:

```
sudo npm install -g graceful-fs
```

and get:

```
+ graceful-fs@4.1.11
added 1 package in 0.678s
```

but when I run `npm install` I get:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:babylon@^7.0.0-beta
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/grim/.npm/_logs/2018-02-08T17_08_50_619Z-debug.log
```

and in the file log it shows:

```
116 error code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
117 error Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:babylon@^7.0.0-beta
```

so I went to [The Problem with gulp-util](https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5) but when I do:

```
npm ls gulp-util
```

I get `└── (empty)`.

Further research I found [Why is my npm install not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40459124/why-is-my-npm-install-not-working) but that throws an `npm ERR!`  What am I doing wrong and how can I get `npm` successfully installed on my Mac running Seirra?

What caused this was trying to test `RNTester` from the [react native repo](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/RNTester) and it told me:

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/react-native.git
cd react-native
npm install
```

---

**Edit**

Per the suggested answer already tried `brew install node` and was told with a warning `node 9.5.0 is already installed` so tried `brew link node` then prompted:

```
grim ~/react-native/react-native brew link node
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/node/9.5.0... 
Error: Could not symlink bin/node
Target /usr/local/bin/node
already exists. You may want to remove it:
  rm '/usr/local/bin/node'

To force the link and overwrite all conflicting files:
  brew link --overwrite node

To list all files that would be deleted:
  brew link --overwrite --dry-run node
```

so ran `brew link --overwrite node`.

---

**Edit**

Browsing through my files under `Users/grim` I found a directory with modules in it named `node_modules` could that be in the wrong location?

---

**Edit**

After further research I found [Fixing npm On Mac OS X for Homebrew Users](https://gist.github.com/DanHerbert/9520689) and ran:

```
rm -rf /usr/local/lib/node_modules
brew uninstall node
brew install node --without-npm
echo prefix=~/.npm-packages >> ~/.npmrc
curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | sh
```

modified my `~/.bash_profile` with nano:

```
export PATH="$HOME/.npm-packages/bin:$PATH"
```

ran `npm install` and received a missing `package.json` file so in the terminal did `npm init` and answered the questions.  Went back and pointed to the cloned repo and when I run `npm install`:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "npm:": npm:babylon@^7.0.0-beta
npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
```

but if I build a new project with `react-native init AwesomeProject` and `npm install` I get:

```
up to date in 0.416s
```

and I can point into the project and do `react-native run-ios` and it works but `react-native run-android` has to be tweaked in the `build.bundle` from: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'` to `classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0"`

Comment: Did you find an answer? If so, care to share?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Homebrew for Mac as package manager;

https://brew.sh/

then you can run:  brew install node

There are many other utilities on this.

Comment: Already tried that and it still throws the error.  Will make an edit.

Comment: Thanks of this answer. it works for me

Answer (score 0):

create-react-native app does not work with npm 5.

I had the same problem on Windows and downgraded my npm to 4 you can use npm i -g npm@4 to downgrade.

Comment: Interesting I'll test this out later tonight and get back to you.  The issue I'm running is on legacy apps but when I create a new app with unit I don't have an issue until rendering in android

Comment: Yeah, hope that will fix your problem too. I had this issue on Windows with node LTS version and npm 5 digged deep in React's Github and found the suggested solution was to downgrade npm to 4

Comment: sadly that didnt work and throws a checkPermsission warning and path error

Answer (score 0):

You may try to use yarn command with -W flag (or --ignore-workspace-root-check) which might be helpful.

info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Regards